# No eth0 on OVH 18.04 server

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, ethernet

I am trying to follow the step by step on OVH for setting up their vrack on Ubuntu 18.04 but it says there should be an interface called eth0 with `link: detached` in it's info.  I have interfaces for lo, eno3, en04 and then about 20 or so named with hash string that I believe are docker networks on the box.

I googled issue and found mention of: `/etc/network/interfaces`.  For me this file does not exist.

The server works fine over the internet, all my sites are visible, but now I need to configure local networking so I can setup a swarm.

I am just using the default Ubuntu 18.04 image from OVH.  What is right thing to do?

This is docs I am following: https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/configuring-vrack-on-dedicated-servers/

Should I just enter this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
           address 192.168.0.1
           netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Into `/etc/network/interfaces`?

I dont understand why eth0 isn't there.  It doesn't match the docs so I am a bit lost.

Comment: literally from your guide `we’ve used the names of eth1 and eno4 for the secondary network interface. Your servers may use a different naming convention. `   so in your situation the naming works as en03 = eth0; en04=eth1

Comment: As well, `/etc/network/interfaces` is no longer used in 18.04. The correct file is in netplan.

Comment: @chili555 there is no file in /etc/netplan either.  Do I need to create it from scratch?

Comment: What does this tell us? `ls /etc/netplan`

Comment: it was empty but I created a netplan config based on docs (not sure if it worked).  I am trying to create second node atm to see if it works.